# Resources for concrete understanding of fields

Tags: reference-request, field-theory

I'm looking for a textbook that provides exercises for developing intuition about fields themselves, rather than extentions. For example I can't really picture in my head what $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ or $\bar{\mathbb{Z}_p}$ 'look like'.

Answer (score 1):

Extensions are definitely one of the most important tools for understanding fields - they describe how one field is contained in another. Avoiding them would be like saying that you want to get an intuition for each individual part of a car, but don't want to think about how they fit together. For a famous exammple, when we talk about Galois groups, we talk about the Galois group *of an extension*, $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$.  And the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ of the finite field with $p$ elements $\mathbb{F}_p$ is just the union of all the finite extensions $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$, so understanding them and how they fit together is very important - in particular, that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ if and only if $n\mid m$.

Moreover, since any ring homomorphism from one field to another is necessarily injective, avoiding the study of extensions is practically the same as avoiding homomorphisms! Surely you can agree that they are important.

In terms of books that cover the general structure theory of fields, and have exercises, I would suggest:

- [Field Arithmetic](https://books.google.com/books/about/?id=PqxKAQAAIAAJ) by Michael D. Fried, Moshe Jarden
- [Algebra: Volume 1](https://books.google.com/books/about/?id=fvds80NN138C) and [Algebra: Volume II](https://books.google.com/books/about/?id=SUbv_EoUPo8C) by Falko Lorenz
- [Algebraic Extensions of Fields](https://books.google.com/books?id=dC5HvUrfy44C) by Paul J. McCarthy

Another book without exercises is

- [Field Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=QqFIvW85Yt0C) by Gregory Karpilovsky

Comment: I am aware of all the points you made. I'm just looking for a collection of exercises about the first order properties of fields. i.e. a finite subgroup of the multilpicative group is cyclics. Also I'd like to disagree about the point about thinking of fields as their affine schemes. I don't believe it offers any insight at all.